# How to find address in QGIS using openlayers plug-in?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-openlayers-plugin

Is possible to search for addresses using OpenLayers plugin in QGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QGIS Openlayers is not Google Maps!

What you trying to do is also known as `geocoding`.
Can be for instance accomplished with

- the MMQGIS plugin -> geocode
- The OSM place search plugin
- The Geocode plugin
  and likely many more...

Or you could just use google maps and copy/paste the resulting longitude and latitude values into the address-bar in QGIS for a direct focus

Comment: Of course qgis+OL it's not the GM,I wanted to get a place directly in qgis. Thanks for the help, when I have time I will try to make a plugin with something like that.